# How to make a button call on a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

So I am trying to make a button that randomly generates hamster names for a class I'm taking.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CS 105: Name That Hamster</title>

    <!-- JavaScript for Lab 4 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lab4.js"></script>

    <script language = "JavaScript">
function processRequest(){
var target = document.getElementById("nameField");
var result = target.innerHTML;
result = parseInt(result)
target.HTML = result +1;}
</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Additional CS 105 Stylesheet Rules -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cs105.cs.illinois.edu/res/cs105.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cs105-mp-header" id="content">
        <div class="container"> 
            <h1>Lab 4: Name That Hamster</h1>
            <p>When complete, this tool will randomly name your (or anybody else's) hamster using on of the 1000 most popular baby names for each gender (Social Security Data for children born in 1997)</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Please select your hamster's gender!</h3>
            <p>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderF" value="M">It's a Girl!<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderM" value="F">It's a Boy!<br>
                <button onClick="processRequest"> Name That Hamster!</button> 

            <p id="nameField"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My button is currently unresponsive when I click on it. I need it to pop up a name of a hamster, but when I click on it now, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

1) The javascript declaration is incorrect

```
<script type = "JavaScript">
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

2) You need to add brackets in your function call (without brackets is just a reference to a function):

```
<button onClick="processRequest()">
```

That should work.

Comment: As this looks like a HTML5 app, `<script>` on it's own should work.

Comment: agreed, i checked both actually

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding `alert(result)` at the end of your function to see if the function gets triggered.
2. If it does, then it means your function contains error. I think it should be written like this :

   ```
   function processRequest(){
       var target = document.getElementById("nameField");
       var result = target.innerHTML;
       result = parseInt(result)
       target.innerHTML = result +1; //<---- HERE, add innerHTML
   }
   ```
3. Where is the array of names? In lab4.js? If so you should get the names from here, and not put the `result + 1` inside your target.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would add an ID to the button and use Javascript to create event listener. Below I've added the ID of 'buttonClick' to the button and added event listeners (recognize the click) to run the function you want. Notice the alerts I have added too, just to check whether the event and function gets called :

```js
document.getElementById('buttonClick').addEventListener('click',function(){
  alert('click')
  return processRequest();
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CS 105: Name That Hamster</title>

    <!-- JavaScript for Lab 4 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lab4.js"></script>

    <script language = "JavaScript">
function processRequest(){
  
var target = document.getElementById("nameField");
var result = target.innerHTML;
alert('Result : ' + result )
result = parseInt(result)
target.HTML = result +1;}
</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Additional CS 105 Stylesheet Rules -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cs105.cs.illinois.edu/res/cs105.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cs105-mp-header" id="content">
        <div class="container"> 
            <h1>Lab 4: Name That Hamster</h1>
            <p>When complete, this tool will randomly name your (or anybody else's) hamster using on of the 1000 most popular baby names for each gender (Social Security Data for children born in 1997)</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Please select your hamster's gender!</h3>
            <p>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderF" value="M">It's a Girl!<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderM" value="F">It's a Boy!<br>
                <button id='buttonClick' onclick="processRequest"> Name That Hamster!</button> 

            <p id="nameField" style='display:none'>Fred (TEST NAME)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice I have added the name 'Fred (TEST NAME) in the `<p>` with ID 'nameField'. This is just to test if it's working :)